# Removing rows and columns with only NaN from numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, nan

I am looking for a solution to this problem.

While experimenting with masks I got this error and have no clue why.
It works for rows but not for columns?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[1, np.nan, 0],
    [0, np.nan, 0],
    [0, np.nan, 0],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [2, np.nan, 4]])

mask_row = np.all(np.isnan(a), axis=1)
mask_column = np.all(np.isnan(a), axis=0)
print(a[~mask_row])
print(a[~mask_column])
```

This is the error I get for the last print statement:

```py
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 5 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `mask_column` is `array([False,  True, False])`.

In particular `mask_column.shape` is `(3,)` i.e. 1 dimensional of size 3, while `a.shape` is `(5,3)`, thus `mask_column` cannot be broadcasted (check [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for detailed broadcast explaination).

Therefore to filter nan columns you need to pass such mask as second dimension after selecting all the rows, namely:

```
print(a[:, ~mask_column])
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [nan nan]
 [ 2.  4.]]
```